# Postfix - add x-header to show which transport has been used

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have postfix configured with multiple IP's using round robin transport.

How can I add an x-header to detail which of the transports was used to send the email ?

ie so on a received email i could look at the headers and see which transport was used.

many thanks!

Comment: So, you want to add or edit headers? The `header_checks` feature can do this. Note the `Received` header is parsed by recipients with some expectations about the structure, so if its something you only use locally anyway, be careful about which information to add where (or whether to even add an entirely separate header).

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44123/add-header-to-outgoing-email-with-postfix

Comment: so, i know how to add a header, but how can i pick up the transport name used and add that as a header value ?

ie, if transport "smtp1"‪ is used, i add X-HEADER:Transport SMTP1  as an example

Comment: I'm not sure how you've set up the multiple IP's, but assuming every IP has a separate entry in your `master.cf`, you could add a `-o header_checks = pcre:[...]` for every IP separately. This means you'd have to create a header_checks-file per IP.